# Need Assistance with following ```HTML``` Error?

Tags: php, html

I am getting the following validation error, it claims I have "misplaced non-space characters inside the table" I have tried everything and for the life of me cannot fix this error. The error is the following

[image]

Here is the `PHP/HTML` being used for

```
<?php
$title = "Alter Records";
include('includes/head.php');
include('includes/nav.php');
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
require_once('config.php');
require_once('db_class.php');
$connection = new dbController(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$sql = "select id,name, image,location from location";

$results = $connection->getAllRecords($sql);
//var_dump($results);
 ?>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th colspan="2">Make Changes</th>
</tr>;
<?php

foreach ($results as $row){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>{$row['id']}</td>";
  echo "<td>{$row['name']}</td>";
  echo "<td>{$row['location']}</td>";
  echo "<td><img class='thumb' src='{$row['image']}'  alt='{$row['name']}'> </td>";
  echo "<td><a href=''>Update</a></td>";
  echo "<td><a href='delete_record.php?id={$row['id']}'>Delete</a></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
include('includes/footer.php')
 ?>
```

Here is the code inside `validator.w3.org`

```
↩
<!DOCTYPE html>↩
<html lang="en">↩
<head>↩
<meta charset="utf-8">↩
<title>Alter Records</title>↩
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">↩
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bellota+Text:ital,wght@1,300;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">↩
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">↩
</head>↩
<body>↩
<header><h1> TOURISM VICTORIA</h1></header>↩
<nav>↩
<ul class="flex-nav">↩
  <li><a href="Home.php">Home</a></li>↩
  <li><a href="FORM.php">Add</a></li>↩
  <li><a href="modify_table.php">Alter</a></li>↩
  <li>↩
    <form class="search-form" action="search.php" method="get">↩
      <input type="text" name="search">↩
      <button type="submit">Search</button>↩
    </form>↩
  </li>↩
</ul>↩
</nav>↩
<table>↩
<tr>↩
    <th>Id</th>↩
    <th>Name</th>↩
    <th>Location</th>↩
    <th>Image</th>↩
    <th colspan="2">Make Changes</th>↩
</tr>;↩
<tr><td>1</td><td>Melbourne ShowGrounds</td><td>Royal Melbourne Showgrounds. Ascot Vale, Victoria, Austra
```

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated. If I am still unclear, please ask for further clarification.

Comment: Remove `;` after `<th colspan="2">Make Changes</th>`

Comment: Will try right now, thank you for the response

Comment: Error Fix, thank you.

Comment: Hey Robin, as your comment was acknowledged by Adam as the solution, please move your comment into an answer so that Adam can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just seeing your last `include` will also result in an error, you will need to end with `;`